# Is the ring $K=\mathbb R[t] /( t^3+1)$ integral domain and/or a field? What's $[K: \mathbb R]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is the ring $K=\mathbb R[t] / (t^3+1)$ integral domain and/or a field? What's $[K:R]$?

Since $t^3+1$ is reducible over $\mathbb R$, $K$ isn't a field. How do I check whether it's an integral domain?

Also, how do I calculate this (bizarre?) degree $[K: \mathbb R]$? Maybe it's a typo and should be $[K:\mathbb R[x]]$? How do I calculate it then?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: $t^3+1$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$... $(-1)^3+1=0$...

Comment: $t^3 + 1 = (t - 1)(t^2 + t + 1)$ isn't irreducible over $\Bbb R$. Also, when you write $R$, do you mean $\Bbb R$?

Comment: oops, my bad! Will fix it right away!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the 'degree' $[K:\mathbb{R}]$ isn't defined since $K$ isn't a field.

Comment: Yeah, it was asked in case it were a field. How would I calculated it then?

Comment: @Hayden: $[K : \mathbb{R}]$ is well-defined for any $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $K$ (as the dimension of $K$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space). Admittedly that notation is usually reserved for field extensions, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ring is not an integral domain. Since $t+1$ and $t^2-t+1$ are non zero elements, however their product is $t^3+1=0$.